# The SQL Server query is taking too long to load the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

The below query is actually a view which is being used to display the cash payment report. But it is taking too much of time to load the data

```
SELECT
        Billing_AccountPaymentDate.DueDate,
        SUM(Billing_AccountCharge.NetAmount) AS NetCharges,
        ISNULL(SUM(AccountChargePayment.SchoolPayments + AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittances + AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittancesPending), 0) / SUM(Billing_AccountCharge.NetAmount) AS PercentCollected,
        SUM(Billing_AccountCharge.NetAmount - ISNULL(AccountChargePayment.SchoolPayments + AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittances + AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittancesPending, 0)) AS RemainingBalance,
        Billing_AccountPaymentDate.RemittanceEffectiveDate,
        Billing_Account.SchoolId,
        ISNULL(SUM(AccountChargePayment.SchoolPayments), 0) AS SchoolPayments,
        ISNULL(SUM(AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittances), 0) AS SchoolRemittances,
        ISNULL(SUM(AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittancesPending), 0) AS SchoolRemittancesPending,
        Billing_Account.SchoolYearId,
        ISNULL(SUM(AccountChargePayment.SchoolPayments + AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittances), 0) AS TotalReceipts
    FROM
        Billing_AccountCharge
    INNER JOIN
        Billing_AccountInvoice ON
        Billing_AccountInvoice.AccountInvoiceId = Billing_AccountCharge.AccountInvoiceId
    INNER JOIN
        Billing_Account ON
        Billing_Account.AccountId = Billing_AccountInvoice.AccountId
    INNER JOIN
        Billing_PaymentMethod ON
        Billing_PaymentMethod.PaymentMethodId = CASE WHEN Billing_AccountInvoice.AutomaticPaymentEligible = 1 THEN Billing_Account.PaymentMethodId ELSE 3 END -- Send Statements
    INNER JOIN
        Billing_AccountPaymentDate ON
        Billing_AccountPaymentDate.AccountPaymentMethodId = Billing_PaymentMethod.AnticipatedAccountPaymentMethodId AND
        Billing_AccountPaymentDate.DueDate = Billing_AccountInvoice.DueDate AND
        Billing_AccountPaymentDate.HoldForFee = Billing_Account.HoldPaymentForFee
    INNER JOIN
        Billing_ChargeItem ON
        Billing_ChargeItem.ChargeItemId = Billing_AccountCharge.ChargeItemId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                Billing_AccountChargePayment.AccountChargeId,
                SUM(CASE WHEN Billing_AccountPayment.AccountPaymentTypeId = 9 THEN Billing_AccountChargePayment.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS SchoolPayments,
                SUM(CASE WHEN Billing_AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittanceId IS NOT NULL THEN Billing_AccountChargePayment.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS SchoolRemittances,
                SUM(CASE WHEN Billing_AccountChargePayment.SchoolRemittanceId IS NULL AND Billing_AccountPayment.AccountPaymentTypeId <> 9 THEN Billing_AccountChargePayment.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS SchoolRemittancesPending
            FROM
                Billing_AccountChargePayment
            INNER JOIN
                Billing_AccountPayment ON
                Billing_AccountPayment.AccountPaymentId = Billing_AccountChargePayment.AccountPaymentId
            GROUP BY
                Billing_AccountChargePayment.AccountChargeId
        ) AccountChargePayment ON
        AccountChargePayment.AccountChargeId = Billing_AccountCharge.AccountChargeId
    WHERE
        Billing_AccountInvoice.AccountInvoiceStatusId <> 4 AND -- Voided
        Billing_ChargeItem.RemitToSchool = 1
        AND Billing_Account.[SchoolId] = 6  --hard code in a school with data
AND Billing_Account.[SchoolYearId] = 12   --hard code in a school year with data
    GROUP BY
        Billing_AccountPaymentDate.DueDate,
        Billing_AccountPaymentDate.RemittanceEffectiveDate,
        Billing_Account.SchoolId,
        Billing_Account.SchoolYearId
    HAVING
        SUM(Billing_AccountCharge.NetAmount) <> 0
        order by Billing_AccountPaymentDate.DueDate ASC
```

It looks like the inner query in the left join is taking too much of time, both the tables already have non clustered index, I tried taking those tables outside but the data is not accurate

Comment: HOw long is "too long"? How long is the query actually taking? HOw long is an acceptable time to you?

Comment: Are you also about the [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: Did you check the execution plan? Are the join or filtering columns covered by indexes?

Comment: That nested query is *definitely* causing a delay, as expected, because the database has to calculate its result for the entire table before it can join it with the rest of the query and possibly discard non matching rows. The JOIN is performed on the output's `AccountChargeId` column, not `Billing_AccountChargePayment.AccountChargeId`

Comment: It's also subject to divide-by-zero errors.

Comment: The response time is somewhere around 50 secs and above. Wherein we expect it to be less than 10 secs

Answer (score -1):

Use CTE instead of subquery and do all calculation there instead of in Left outer join. Moreover, use with(nolock) whenever you fetch data. Still your query is taking much more time then You should implement proper indexing.

```
WITH PaymentData AS (
  SELECT
    acp.AccountChargeId,
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN ap.AccountPaymentTypeId = 9 THEN acp.Amount
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS SchoolPayments,
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN acp.SchoolRemittanceId IS NOT NULL THEN acp.Amount
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS SchoolRemittances,
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN acp.SchoolRemittanceId IS NULL AND ap.AccountPaymentTypeId <> 9 THEN acp.Amount
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS SchoolRemittancesPending
  FROM
    Billing_AccountChargePayment acp WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Billing_AccountPayment ap  WITH(NOLOCK) ON acp.AccountPaymentId = ap.AccountPaymentId
  GROUP BY
    acp.AccountChargeId
)
SELECT
  apd.DueDate,
  SUM(ac.NetAmount) AS NetCharges,
  COALESCE(
    SUM(pd.SchoolPayments + pd.SchoolRemittances + pd.SchoolRemittancesPending),
    0
  ) / SUM(ac.NetAmount) AS PercentCollected,
  SUM(ac.NetAmount - COALESCE(pd.SchoolPayments, 0) - COALESCE(pd.SchoolRemittances, 0) - COALESCE(pd.SchoolRemittancesPending, 0)) AS RemainingBalance,
  apd.RemittanceEffectiveDate,
  a.SchoolId,
  COALESCE(SUM(pd.SchoolPayments), 0) AS SchoolPayments,
  COALESCE(SUM(pd.SchoolRemittances), 0) AS SchoolRemittances,
  COALESCE(SUM(pd.SchoolRemittancesPending), 0) AS SchoolRemittancesPending,
  a.SchoolYearId,
  COALESCE(SUM(pd.SchoolPayments + pd.SchoolRemittances), 0) AS TotalReceipts
FROM
  Billing_AccountCharge ac  WITH(NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN Billing_AccountInvoice ai  WITH(NOLOCK) ON ac.AccountInvoiceId = ai.AccountInvoiceId
  INNER JOIN Billing_Account a  WITH(NOLOCK) ON ai.AccountId = a.AccountId
  INNER JOIN Billing_PaymentMethod pm  WITH(NOLOCK) ON pm.PaymentMethodId = CASE
    WHEN ai.AutomaticPaymentEligible = 1 THEN a.PaymentMethodId
    ELSE 3
  END
  INNER JOIN Billing_AccountPaymentDate apd WITH(NOLOCK) ON
    apd.AccountPaymentMethodId = pm.AnticipatedAccountPaymentMethodId AND
    apd.DueDate = ai.DueDate AND
    apd.HoldForFee = a.HoldPaymentForFee
  INNER JOIN Billing_ChargeItem ci  WITH(NOLOCK) ON ac.ChargeItemId = ci.ChargeItemId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PaymentData pd  WITH(NOLOCK) ON ac.AccountChargeId = pd.AccountChargeId
WHERE
  ai.AccountInvoiceStatusId <> 4 AND 
  ci.RemitToSchool = 1 AND
  a.SchoolId = 6 AND
  a.SchoolYearId = 12
GROUP BY
  apd.DueDate,
  apd.RemittanceEffectiveDate,
  a.SchoolId,
  a.SchoolYearId
HAVING
  SUM(ac.NetAmount) <> 0
ORDER BY
  apd.DueDate ASC;
```

Comment: the response time is still the same. What do you mean by proper Indexing? Shall I make an index where all the columns used here from Billing_AccountChargePayment table be used? Sorry if this sound non sense but I am not well versed with sql hence this question. Because most of these columns have separate indexes

Comment: And Just I want to know that CTE query is taking time or not?

Otherwise, You should try one more thing that comment all joins and start to execute query from the beginning after that remove comment one by one so you can easily able to find out which join is more taking time. This is debugging similar we do in .net.

Comment: I have a doubt here, If I take out the create table script from SSMS for this table i get below script wherein i can see only CLustered Index. Although If i go inside indexes folder for this table there are multiple Indexes. Does that mean, all those non clustered ones are not associated to this

Comment: It is in a view which is being accessed by .net project

Comment: Also, more indexing can effect on performance so remove unnecessary uncultured index. But first try with debugging and find out that which join is taking much time.

Comment: Like this and remove comment one by one
SELECT ac.*
FROM  Billing_AccountCharge ac  WITH(NOLOCK)
--INNER JOIN Billing_AccountInvoice ai  WITH(NOLOCK) ON ac.AccountInvoiceId = ai.AccountInvoiceId
 --INNER JOIN Billing_Account a  WITH(NOLOCK) ON ai.AccountId = a.AccountId

Comment: CTE is taking way too longer to execute

Comment: have you checked by executing CTE query separate?

Comment: Yes checked that too. And if I remove that cte left join the query gets executed in 2 secs

Comment: Then now try to improve CTE query performance problem is there

Comment: But how is the question? DO you have any alternates

Comment: if I have data then I can check it

Comment: *" Moreover, use with(nolock) "* This is terrible advice when you don't tell the OP the *dangers* of using it. `NOLOCK` is not a "magic go faster" button, and *spamming* it against **every** table is never the correct choice; that's what isolation levels are for. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Larnu
The NOLOCK hint allows SQL to read data from tables by ignoring any locks and therefore not get blocked by other processes.
This can improve query performance by removing the blocks, but introduces the possibility of dirty reads.
Read further to better understand the use of NOLOCK.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/#:~:text=The%20NOLOCK%20hint%20allows%20SQL,understand%20the%20use%20of%20NOLOCK.

Comment: *I* know what `NOLOCK` does, @DarshanBalar , however, you don't explain the dangers of using it in your answer. It also doesn't make sense to *spam* `NOLOCK` against every object. Why not just recommend changing the isolation level if you're going to use `NOLOCK` against *every* table?

Comment: Yes @Larnu You right there are some drawback of using NOLOCK and I was not explaining the answer of drawback of NOLOCK. She was facing issue query. It was taking too much time so there were possibility that might be in she's query facing locks therefore tables not get blocked by other processes that's why I gave NOLOCK suggestion.